# Point-splitting regularization for anomaly in curved spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, qft-in-curved-spacetime, regularization, quantum-anomalies

In flat spacetime, the point-splitting regularization for (chiral) anomaly is discussed in great details in Peskin and Schroeder's QFT.

Does anyone know any good references for calculating anomaly using the point-splitting regularization in curved spacetime?

Comment: My first guess would be to go check out DeWitt's book on QFT. Has to be there somewhere...

Comment: can you specify the book name you referred to? is that called, "Quantum field theory in curved spacetime"

Comment: I was thinking of "The global approach to QFT", but no guarantee that this is actually answered there, you will have to check!